# How to define partial views in node.js with Express 2.5

Tags: node.js, express

I need to define the skeleton for my node.js app with a menu that needs to be different for logged and anonymous user.

I think that the correct way should be the use of partials (i use Express 2.5) but i don't know how to pass data from the app and the partial. Do i need to add a condition in the layout to embed loggedPartial.ejs or anonymousPartial.ejs?

I'm sure there must be a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using layouts instead of partials?

Comment: @robertklep i would prefer to use express 2.5, if possible

Comment: Never mind about layouts, see my upcoming answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your route:

```
res.render('main', { menu : 'loggedPartial' }); // or 'anonymousPartial'
```

Your main template:

```
<%- partial(menu) %>
```

No need to use a conditional statement, `menu` is expanded dynamically during rendering.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert, you helped me a lot!